# Are there any methods to represent integers in forms like $2^k$*(odd number)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I recently encountered this form of representation of integer numbers:
$a_j=2^{k_j}q_j$, where $k_j$ is a non negative integer and $q_j$ is odd. My question is from where one can get idea of representing integers in this kind of forms?

Comment: You just factor out as many 2's as possible.  Once you can't factor out any more, the result must be odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This representation comes from the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), and changes a nonzero integer into a unique pair of integers, one nonnegative and the other odd.  We can do more:

$$a_j=2^{k_j}3^{i_j}q_j$$
Now, $k_j$ and $i_j$ are nonnegative integers, and $q_j$ is a nonzero integer having no divisors in common with $6$.  This representation is also unique, now as a triple.

There's nothing special about $2$, or $2$ and $3$; any primes can be used in this manner.  All that matters is that the leftover bit, the $q_j$, has none of those primes dividing it.